# Javascript: find out if the URL is equal to a string, with or without trailing slash

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have the following conditional statement in JS:

```
if(url === 'http://www.productionlocations.com/locations' || url === 'http://www.productionlocations.com/locations/')
```

I'm trying to make it more efficient so I tried this:

```
function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
    if(str.substr(-1) == '/') {
        return str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
    }
    return str;
}

theurl = stripTrailingSlash(url);                   
if(theurl === 'http://www.productionlocations.com/locations')
```

But obviously that just makes it into more code :)

What's the most efficient way of doing this? I had tried using indexOf() before, but it didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The conditional statement does not strip anything. If the stripping is not essentiell, do not do it!

Comment: A simpler way to remove a tailing slash: `str.replace(/\\$/, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

```
if(/^http:\/\/www\.productionlocations\.com\/locations\/?$/.test(url)) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: It makes it hard to see the original test URL, and harder to maintain if the URL changes.

Comment: There is over 9000 solutions to check. I've provide mine ;)

Comment: if(/\/locations\/?$/.test(url))

Is totally doable. And accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to check domain.